# How to generate random values without duplication when collision is likely and expensive?

Tags: random

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but they all seem different in one key respect: my collision management problem is more challenging.

My sample space is sequences of the form `aaaaa`, where a is letter [a-z]. So that's 26^5 = 11,881,376 combinations.  (Note that I have a fairly small word size (5) and alphabet size (26). This is because I need reasonably memorable words. This means that I might have to assign around one million of the 12 million total possibiliites, which means that collision would be far more likely than, say, choosing 100 integers out of 2^32 possible ones.)

Also, I need to generate a random value and it must not collide with any existing values, but these existing values are generated over a long period of time and stored in a database. In other words, I don't have them in memory for an easy collision check.

Most algorithms for generating a random value without duplication involve generating a value and just testing it for a collision, and repeating until there is no collision. But here that test would mean a database call, which would be much more expensive, and my collision rate is much higher. So I think I will have problems.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it not possible to pre-generate all values then pop them randomly? From some quick math, it doesn't seem like that would require *that* much memory. Like ~50mb depending on the type? That should be manageable.

Comment: What kind of resources do the random identifiers identify?  Do you need the identifiers to be hard to guess, or merely random-looking, or merely sequential?  If they need to be random, are those identifiers the only thing that grants access to those resources?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that your universe is small: Populate an array with all 12 million. Shuffle the array so that they are in random order. Populate a database table with them, indexed (i.e., database rows look like (1, "hgfyu"), (2, "aipes"), (3, "zdpgb"), etc.).

Then just keep track (in another table) how many you've handed out, and when you need another, just hand out the "next" one and increment your count.

Another possibility with more math, less storage: just keep track of how many you've handed out. Then whenever you need a new one, use a reproducible RNG to find the Nth random number in a fixed sequence (call it K), then return the lexicographically Kth code.

Comment: I understand your first suggestion, but I'm not quite following the second one. How would you generate the Nth one efficiently when N is large, and how would you ensure that there were no collisions such that K is also the (N - i)th number for some i?

Comment: Generating the Kth in lexicographic sequence is trivial--just treat the letters as digits in base 26. You avoid collision by choosing the right generator--something like an LFSR or specialized block cipher. Like I said, lots of math, but doable.

Comment: I understand how to index the words, but with a LFSR, don't you have to run through all N steps to produce that Nth term? When N gets large, that would become expensive.

Comment: You keep the state of the LFSR persistent, so you only need to generate the next state (and possibly do some rejection sampling) for each use.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use a hashed counter; simply maintain a counter from 0 to 11,881,375 and apply some bijective mapping function to that so they're produced in random order.

Something like:

```
// map any value < 2**24 to another value < 2**24, with no duplicates
int hash24(int x) {
  x = x ^ (x >> 12);
  x = (x * 0x818d6b) & 0xffffff;
  x = x ^ (x >> 10);
  x = (x * 0x0fa653) & 0xffffff;
  x = x ^ (x >> 12);
  return x;
}

void next(char result[6]) {
  static int s = 0;    // keep this value somewhere persistent
  const int seq = 0x55aa55;    // change this to re-randomize
  int r;

  // find the next random value less than 26**5
  do {
    r = hash24(s ^ seq);
    s = s + 1;
  } while (result >= 11881376);

  // map integer to string of letters
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    result[i] = 'a' + (r % 26);
    r /= 26;
  }
  result[5] = '\0';
}
```

However, it seems likely that you have more constraints which you haven't mentioned.  You might want to avoid words that won't be memorable because they're perfect gibberish (like a YouTube URL) and at the same time you might want to avoid offensive words (no idea if YouTube filters these, but I haven't seen one).

Because 26 is divisible by two it's fairly straightforward to make a version that doesn't rely on rejecting out-of-range values, but it's an unnecessarily weird thing to do:

```
int hash26p5(int x) {
  int r[5] = { 5, 11, 17, 23, 27 };
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    int r = ((x & 31) * r[i]) & 31;
    x = (x >> 5) + r * 371293;
  }
  return x;
}

void next(char result[6]) {
  static int s = 0;    // keep this value somewhere persistent
  int r hash26p5(s);
  s = s + 1;

  // map integer to string of letters
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    result[i] = 'a' + (r % 26);
    r /= 26;
  }
  result[5] = '\0';
}
```

In fact, because there are only two prime factors more interesting things can be done, but they're even more esoteric, and they wouldn't be relevant if you moved to a smaller alphabet or a different number of letters.

Comment: How did you come up with constants 0x818d6b or 0x0fa653.
I want to design a similar function but I'm not sure how to approach that.
Could you recommend some resources I could learn that from ?

Comment: They came from a search [inspired](https://www.tīkōuka.dev/n-bit-mixer-functions/) by [Austin Appleby](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) and [David Stafford](https://zimbry.blogspot.com/2011/09/better-bit-mixing-improving-on.html).